# how to open a table view from clicking on a table view cell in Xamarin4

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

[SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyxei.png)I am new to both Xamarin and C#,

I'm wondering how do I open a new table view controller from pressing on a table view cell in Xamarin? Right now my app opens my table view and it's programmed so when a cell from that table view is pressed a pop up opens saying "Row Selected... etc."

Thank You

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace App2

{
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        string[] TableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public TableSource(string[] items)
        {
            TableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return TableItems.Length;
        }

        public static string SelectedRow;

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            new UIAlertView("Row Selected", TableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK").Show();
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

            SelectedRow = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
        }


        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
            string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
            { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you show us the code you've got so far we can help you a little more. It makes it easier for us to provide a more accurate example based off of your own code, rather than an example from a guide.

Comment: So you want to display a new view after a tableview item is selected instead of displaying a pop up?

Comment: Correct. That display was only for testing purposes.

Comment: Do not post code as a screenshot; put the code in your question.

Comment: In what way are you using the item selected?

Comment: I have a bit more code in my view controller. What i want is once a user clicks on my tableview cell for example lets say the table is a list of animals (dogs, cats, fish,etc) i want it to open up another tableview controller once clicked. So if the user was to click on dogs i could have a list/table of the types of dogs i.e.(golden,lab,etc)

Answer (score -1):

There is a recipe for this on the Xamarin [website](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/handle_a_row_click/). This shows how to handle a tableview tap event. To present the new viewcontroller, you would do something similar to this

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

 ViewController vc = new ViewController();
 PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/gradyjenkins/Practicum/blob/master/CurrentLocationTracker/FriendsTableViewController.swift) is another resource. It is a tableview populated with different friends and when the user selects one of the rows it will segue into another view with information on the selected row.

Comment: This is for Xamarin.Forms, his screenshot looks like a native xamarin.ios project.

Comment: Yea its just a single view ios application

Comment: Edited, lemme know if that helps or not @R.Drake

Comment: @R.Drake Sorry, I can't really test it at work right now. I edited my answer with some more resources from one of my projects. Its a list of "friends" and when you click the tableview cell it will segue into another view and display information on that friend.

Comment: @Grady if you get the chance could you see if it works.